# How can I use getChildHtml() for get block from Magento and insert it into Wordpress header?

Tags: wordpress, magento

I have block in Magento (at home page). It's name - `featured_product_slider`

```html
<div class="new-arrivals home-carousel">
   <h2 class="section-title">SHOP NEW ARRIVALS</h2>
   <h2 class="section-title-img"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/title__shop-new-arrivals.png') ?>" /></h2>
   <? echo $this->getChildHtml('featured_product_slider'); //Need to connect this unit?>
</div>
```

This block in XML:

```xml
<block type="site/featured_product_slider" name="featured_product_slider" template="featured/product/slider.phtml">
   <block type="core/text_list" name="product_list.name.after" as="name.after" />
</block>
```

How do I add this block to the Header in WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

**Display the slider.**

Magento Side

1. Create new plugin in Magento
2. Create new route in Magento
3. Create new Controller in Magento
4. Render this `featured_product_slider` in this controller - and nothing more. Just featured_product_slider on blank page
5. This element should be visible at your custom route. So `magento_url.com/route/controller/method`

Wordpress side

1. Use cURL to get content from remote url `magento_url.com/route/controller/method`
2. Check if response is 200
3. Check if content is fine (e.g some preg_match methods) to avoid get any error page in Magento or other crashed case
4. Save the result in cache. Not sure if WordPress offer it. If no -> use any custom cache for it.
5. Implement method to display content from cache in WordPress or if cache do not exist make request, get content, save in cache and display.

Problems

1. You can include the CSS/JS in Magento route. But then you should include only this part of CSS/JS which is used in slider
2. You can copy this part of CSS/JS from Magento to Wordpress

**Clear the cache**

Magento side

1. In Magento Admin panel add plugin "afterSave" method to place where you define items for slider
2. In this plugin make call to Wordpress endpoint to clear cache after change

Wordpress side

1. Implement endpoint which allow to clear from remote request.
2. Be sure that only Magento can use this endpoint